# Converting an array to a key-value object using a method similar to Array.prototype.map()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there any `Array` method **similar** to [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that takes an array and converts it into a key-value object?

Here's an example:

```
var people = [{name: 'person1', tableId: 1}, {name: 'person2', tableId: 2}];
var table = [{id:1, shape:2, title: 'table1'}, {id:2, shape:4, title: 'table2'}];
```

I would like to create a table-people object where the key will be an id and the value would be all the people that have the relevant tableId.

An example for the output will be:

```
var output = {
  1: [{name: 'person1', tableId: 1}, <more people>], 
  2: [{name: 'person2', tableId: 2}}, <more people>]
};
```

`output` will be a key-value object. The key is the tableId and the value is an array of people. A person has some more information(other than name and tableId - this is just a simple example).

Now the easy way to do it is:

```
var output = {};
for(var i = 0 ; i < table.length ; i++)
{
   output[table.id] = getPeopleThatSitInTable(table.id); // will return an array
}
```

Is there any method like:

```
table.keyValueMapObject(function(item){
  return { key: item.id, value: getPeopleThatSitInTable(item.id) }
});
```

This method will create an object behind the scenes, fill it based on key & value and return the object?

I'm **not** looking for something like:

```
var obj = {}; // declaring an object
// loop somehow and fill obj(for\foreach\map\reduce etc.)
```

Since using `for` does the same thing in "the best way".

I'm **looking** for something like:

```
var obj = table.methodName(filterFunction)
```

Comment: [*Array.prototype.map*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19) is generic, you can supply a plain Object as *this*. Can you provide an example of the required output?

Comment: Your code is too confusing and output-input as well. Can you just create a simple input and how a call to a function should produce the output?

Comment: I don't see how the table array fits into the scheme.

Comment: @AmitJoki & RobG - I've edited my post. I'm looking for a key-value mapper. The key will be the tableId and the value will be an array of people who are suppose to sit in that table. I can do the mapping alone with a for\foreach and I was looking for a built in method(similar to Array.prototype.map) that could do that for me. Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 2):

Check [_.groupBy()](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) source. It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Underscore isn't an option for me as for now, but it's good to know that something like this exists, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the most relevant Array method in this case would be `reduce`. Though it doesn't help much, you're reducing the table to a key-value object:

```
var result = table.reduce(function(result, entry) {
    result[entry.id] = people.filter(function(person) { // pretty inefficient
        return person.tableId === entry.id;
    });
    return result;
}, {}); // initial key-value object
```

But actually this use of `reduce` is a bit absurd because the callback doesn't really combine two values. It's just modifying and passing the initial object. While it's making the intent clear it's the same as using `forEach`:

```
var result = {}; // initial key-value object
table.forEach(function(entry) {
    result[entry.id] = people.filter(function(person) { // pretty inefficient
        return person.tableId === entry.id;
    });
});
```

And even then filtering the whole `people` array is pretty inefficient. You should only iterate over it once.

```
var result = {}; // initial key-value object
table.forEach(function(entry) {
    result[entry.id] = [];
});
people.forEach(function(person) {
    result[person.tableId].push(person);
});
```

I don't think there's much potential for simplification.

Of course with the power of [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), [array comprehensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions), [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you could write it as follows:

```
var result = Object.assign({}, ...[{
    [id]: people.filter(
        ({tableId}) => tableId === id
    )
} for({id} of table)]);
```

But it's almost identical to the first version. Again it's inefficient. And it only seems to work in Firefox currently.

I suppose there won't be a native equivalent anytime soon.

Comment: That's the 'primitive' way(for\foreach are equivalent to me). Since I found myself doing this a lot I've created a method that does this - But I'd like to get something built in for this. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` to iterate over tables and construct table-people object by filtering people based on `tableId` as follows,

```
"use strict";

var people = [{name: 'person1', tableId: 1}, {name: 'person2', tableId: 2}];
var table = [{id:1, shape:2, title: 'table1'}, {id:2, shape:4, title: 'table2'}];

var tablePeopleObj = {};
table.forEach(function (tableItem) {
  tablePeopleObj[tableItem.id] = getPeople(tableItem.id);
});


function getPeople(tableId) {
  return people.filter(function function_name (person) {
    return person.tableId == tableId;
  });
}

console.log(tablePeopleObj);
```

Comment: I know about foreach - The problem is that you wont have old browser support and that it's similar to doing a for. I'm looking for a method similar to map that will return an object(based on a key) and not an array. Thank you anyway!!!

Comment: @AmirPopovich—if you are concerned about old browser support, *for* and *for..in* are your only options. ECMAScript ed 3 didn't have iterators for Array and Object.

Comment: @RobG - You're right - lets ignore the old browsers for a second..I'm looking for a solution that doesn't make me declare a var, loop it(for\foreach etc) and do my stuff. I'm looking for an internal method that will do this for me - something similiar to "the map() way". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following uses *Array.prototype.map*, but likely isn't what you want. Consider it just an example of use that might be helpful:

```
var people = [{name: 'person1', tableId: 1}, {name: 'person2', tableId: 2}];
var obj = {};

people.map(function(v, i) {
  var key = v.tableId;
  if (!this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    this[key] = [];
  }
  this[key].push(v);
}, obj);
```

Comment: Still you're declaring an object, filling it up using a loop(or map) and misusing Array.prototype.map. I think it's a lot better to use a simple for\foreach in this case. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you want to "convert" an Array to an Object, then you've got to create a new object. I don't think this is misusing *map*, it's intended to be a generic method for traversing own properties and allows setting of *this*. I think it's more appropriate than *reduce*.